# Password manager for Chrome and IE

Tags: windows-10, password-manager

I use HP Client security on a Windows 10 laptop and it works quite well with all applications, except Chrome. I'm looking for a new password manager which can work with Chrome too.

What I'm looking for:

- password manager which can manage passwords in Chrome AND Internet Explorer
- free
- being able to unlock using fingerprint is a nice to have
- managing passwords of other non-browser applications is a nice to have, but not necessary, I can keep my current tool for them.